# How to close file/buffer/tab after cerain time of inactivity?

Tags: buffers, vim-windows

Is there a way to close file after certain amount of time of user inactivity?
Lets say I have a encrypted file and I want to close it after 10 min. 
Is it possible in Vim?

Answer (score 1):

*Yes, but it doesn't come for free in the form of a ready-to-use option; some assembly required:*

If you define activity as changes done to the buffer, you can periodically sample [`b:changedtick`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#b%3Achangedtick), and record (in a buffer-local variable) a timestamp ([`:help localtime()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#localtime%28%29)) when it changes. If activity includes movements, you can do the same with the cursor position ([`getpos()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getpos%28%29)).

That sampling can be done with [`:autocmd`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aautocmd); the [`CursorHold`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorHold) event can be used for triggering (as long as you allow some flexibility about the time frame for enforcement; as it only fires when Vim is idle).

For closing, this is a lot easier if you're only interested in the *current* buffer / tab page; you just need to sample the current buffer / all visible buffers, and can then use a simple [`:bdelete`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abdelete) / [`:tabclose`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#%3Atabclose). If you also want to kick out other buffers, you'll need to use [`getbufvar()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getbufvar%28%29) to sample all buffers (without moving to it).